# React Native: Redirecting axios to a different address upon error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

**The Setup**: I am currently coding in a group with two Mac users (I am running Linux). We are making a mobile app using React Native. They are testing the app on an iPhone simulator that is not available for Linux. I test the app by serving the package to a physical Android phone. This works fine until I attempt to make an axios request to the local server.
On an axios request, we feed in the endpoint "http://localhost:3001/whatever". Since my copy of the program is running on a mobile device, localhost refers to the device instead of the computer. I can make the request work by changing 'localhost' to my IP address.

So for example,

```
//Instead of
axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/point')
    .then(response => doaThing(response));
//I could do
axios.get('http://my.ip.addr:3001/api/point')
    .then(response => doaThing(response));
```

**The Problem:** Axios works just fine for my team. It won't work for me without alterations. I don't want to make a bunch of tiny alterations to the codebase before every commit. Is there any way to tell axios to try my IP address if the first request can't find the server? Currently axios returns an object with 'request.status = 0' on this error.

**If it's a dumb idea, please tell me:** I tried to fix this by creating a crude wrapper for axios that would make the call, check for an error message, and if it has a status of 0, make a second call. Any response should be returned.

```
export default axiOS = {
  get: async (endpoint = '', body = {}) => {
    await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001${endpoint}`)
      .then(response => response)
      .catch(async err => {
        //if axios cannot find the server, the status code will be 0
        if (err.request.status === 0) {
          await axios.get(`http://my.ip.addr:3001${endpoint}`)
          .then(response => response)
          .catch(err => console.log("GET Error: ", err))
        } else {
          console.log("GET Error: ", err);
        }
      });
  }, //etc. for put, post, and delete
}
```

Being called with

```
let response = axiOS.get('/api/time');
```

Which could make life easier for everyone involved, but I can't seem to resolve the promise before returning an undefined value.

**tl;dr**
So my question has at least two possible solutions

1. Can axios be made to route to a secondary address upon getting an error?
2. Is my code a feasible solution to this problem? If it is, what can I change to return the response to the first successful request?
3. Is there possibly a third solution I haven't considered?

Comment: maybe this could be useful https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/108#issuecomment-164044648 or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47477644/2083099

Comment: Try using using a template string like this:
```${__DEV__ ? (Platfrom.OS === 'ios' ? 'http://localhost' : 'http://x.x.x.x') : 'https://prod.url'}/api/time```

Comment: @dotoconnor That's perfect. That's exactly what I needed. This will work for our purposes. The only drawback is that if any of my teammates load up the app on an Android phone, then the program will hit MY local server instead of theirs. I don't think that's a huge problem though. If you want to post that as a solution, I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

If the application should be distributed to public, the app should somehow know which server to contact. Right now, in development that is `localhost` or a local ip, and later it will most probably be an domain. That said: In each case you need to find a way to configure the app with a url to use. I would recommend to use a `.env` file and somehow poor the url into the source, such that your source code just uses a url from configuration. This way it will be easy to have the final url in your production app.

Comment: I would love to use the .env file to configure this, but as far as I'm aware, React native was not made to understand global variables.

Comment: Doesn't it have any build process you can hook into? Something like webpack ??