# Pass variable endpoint using vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm learning vuex at the moment and wondering if there is a way to pass a different endpoint url in my vuex action? I'm building a simple movie app using a movies API and have numerous buttons that will call the API and post specific categories. What I would like to do is dispatch the same function from vuex but specify which endpoint to use rather than create the same function with just a different endpoint in vuex.

Vuex:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const topTwentyEndpoint =
  'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key='

const theatresEndpoint =
  'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-22&api_key='

export const state = () => ({
  posts: [],
})

export const mutations = {
  setMovies(state, posts) {
    state.posts = posts
  },
}

export const getters = {}

export const actions = {
  getMovies({ commit }) {
    axios.get(topTwentyEndpoint).then((response) => {
      commit('setMovies', response.data.results)
    })
  },
}
```

movies component:

```
<template>
  <form
    id="formGetMovies"
    class="flex flex-col items-start w-3/4 pt-5 get-movies"
  >
    <div class="flex buttons__row">
      <button
        class="py-3 mt-2 mr-5 text-white bg-red-700 rounded-md  hover:bg-red-800 px-7 btn btn__submit btn-disabled"
        :class="{ disabled: moviesShown }"
        :disabled="moviesShown"
        @click.prevent="submitForm"
      >
        Top 20
      </button>
      <button
        class="py-3 mt-2 text-white bg-red-700 rounded-md  hover:bg-red-800 px-7 btn btn__submit btn-disabled"
        :class="{ disabled: moviesShown }"
        :disabled="moviesShown"
        @click.prevent="submitForm"
      >
        In Theatres Now
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'MoviesForm',
  data() {
    return {
      moviesShown: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      this.$store.dispatch('movies/getMovies')
      this.moviesShown = true
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey hendy, what you are looking for is to create two instances of axios. Your question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47477594/how-to-use-2-instances-of-axios-with-different-baseurl-in-the-same-app-vue-js) already.

Comment: @kottartillsalu Awesome! thank you!

Comment: if you still don't understand feel free to tag me and I'll try explain